# Conditionally Disable CheckBox

Tags: c#, if-statement

How do I disable a `CheckBox` for senior citizen if my Age is below 65.

I'm trying to run but it gives me an error inside the if statement...

Here is my code:

```
if (_Age.Text < 65)
{
   _SeniorCitizen.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: `Text` returns a string so you can't compare it to an `int`. You'll have to parse it to an `int` first.

Answer (score 8):

You can use something like:

```
if (int.Parse(_Age.Text) < 65) 
{
     _SeniorCitizen.Enabled = false;
}
else
{
     _SeniorCitizen.Enabled = true;
}
```

Note that `int.Parse` will raise an exception if the user enters something that isn't a number.  You could use `int.TryParse` to avoid that:

```
int age;
if (!int.TryParse(_Age.Text, out age))
{
    // Error case - tell the user to enter a number
}
else
{
    if (age < 65) 
    {
         _SeniorCitizen.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
         _SeniorCitizen.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, not only did you provide an answer but added in something extra to help the OP learn something else.  I'd +1 again if I could.